# Keyboard Shorcut to launch bookmarklet in Chrome for Mac

Tags: google-chrome, mac, bookmarklet

How can I launch a bookmarklet with a keyboard shortcut in Chrome for Mac?

I've assigned mac keyboard shorcuts for them as one usually does in mac, and it works for normal bookmarks (websites) but it doesn't properly trigger the bookmarklet.

Is there anything to be done?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to convert the bookmarklet into an extension (I've used [this](https://sandbox.self.li/bookmarklet-to-extension/) tool and followed instructions), load the extension into chrome, and assign a keyboard shorcut to "Activate Extension" in Chrome in this menu chrome://extensions/shortcuts.